# how do I find my recovery key?

Tags: recovery

I did a hard reset and now am being asked for a recovery key. I do not know what this is nor how to find it. It would much appreciated if you guys could help me solve this problem. Thank You. Jason

Comment: What is the version of OS your phone is running? Is it 8.1 or 10 or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Recovery key is because you had Bitlocker turned on.

You can [find all your recovery keys here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=237614)